# Unix File System: How are file names translated to disk sectors?

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, ext4

A very basic question. What is the exact sequence of steps executed when I try to open a file-descriptor, by providing fully-qualified path to the file.

I am looking for

- how this works on Linux
- given a file name - how is it translated to inode and disk-sector
- does linux file system (specifically ext3 and ext4) maintain some kind of filename to inode mapping?

Comment: It is a very sane curiosity, but you should not care how disk sectors are organized in a file system. The file system driver in the kernel is caring for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition of [tmp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745741/841108):

Files really are [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

Usually, a given file has some entry in some directory pointing to its inode. [Directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29) are mapping names to inodes, and directories are a kind of file. See [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) for what an inode contains (and can be queried by application code), in particular for the various file types (plain file, directory, char or block device, fifo, symlink, ....). So a directory is often a dictionnary (implemented in various, file system specific, ways) mapping strings to inodes. So in the directory `/bin/` there is usually an entry associating `bash` to the inode for the ELF executable of the *bash* shell (i.e. `/bin/bash`). Use [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) -which in turn calls [getdents(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html)- to read the entries in a directory.

It may happen that a given inode is not any more reachable by some name. This happens in particular when a process is [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing a file, then [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)-ing it (while keep the opened file descriptor). This is the preferred way to make temporary files. (They will be released by the kernel when no more processes use them).

It may also happen that a given inode has *several* directories entries pointing to it. (i.e. a file has "several names") This happens with [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) syscall. (symlink files are created with [symlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html)).

See also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [unix file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem) & [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) & [ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) & [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) & [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) & [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) & [comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) wikipages. Read also this old [file system](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html) description (some details are rotten, but the general idea is here, notably the role of [VFS](http://www.coda.cs.cmu.edu/doc/talks/linuxvfs/vfs.ppt%E2%80%8E))

Comment: And how are filenames mapped to inodes? Does this happen at directory level? For examples to open file "/home/bobo/foo/hello.txt", lookups for filename to inode will be done 4 times (at '/' for 'home', at '/home' for 'bobo', at '/home/bobo' for 'foo', at '/home/bobo/foo' for hello.txt. Once inode for the file is known - it points to the block on hard-disk. Then the call to read the block is issued by OS. This filename to block resolution is how it works?

Comment: Follow all the links I have given to you.

Comment: @AmitSharma: Yes the loopup for file-name would happen 4 times(in your example) and on every level(directory), kernel would check whether user has appropriate permission to the directory. However if you really want to understand all the concepts and algorithm you must refer the book which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Kernel executes the following steps when we call "open(filepath)":

1. convert the filename to inode.
2. allocate a new file table entry for the inode, initialize various stuff(per process).
3. allocate user file descriptor entry and store into the file table entry(global data structure).
4. return user file descriptor to caller.

For complete information on internal algorithm you may want to refer the great great classic book **"The Design Of UNIX Operating System" By Maurice J Bach** which describes these concepts and the implementation in detailed way.