# What happens when I fopen a file (RAM and ROM matter)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, file-io, fopen

This question came to my mind because I'm trying to speed up my program.

I read data from a file and as usual I use the classical:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "r");
```

The FILE pointer contains a structure that I don't understand very well.

The main question is: **when I perform `fopen` I put somehow the file into the RAM, or every time I use the file pointer it reads it from the HD?**

OS: Linux Mint, gcc compiler

Comment: Well of course its OS dependent. You can look the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22745741/2724703

Comment: You *can* specifically put the file into your virtual address space, the call for that is `mmap()`. But even with `mmap()` you do not have any guarantee about immediate action on behalf of the system, it may not read anything from disk until you actually try to read from an address that falls into the mmaped memory region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned pointer is a pointer to a black-box structure. You're not supposed to understand the actual structure, just how to use the pointer to it.

As for what's happening, the `fopen` function dynamically allocates this structure (by e..g `malloc`) and returns a pointer. The structure is stored in *virtual memory*, which *might* be in RAM or in the swap (if you have swap enabled). The pointer itself is store where-ever the compiler stores variables (e.g. local variables on the stack, global variables somewhere else). No matter where the variable is stored, it's stored in virtual memory just like the structure, just in another place.

Then comes the file-handling operations. By default all file-streams are *buffered*, meaning that when you try to read anything from a `FILE` pointer, the function you call will read into a private buffer, and return to you a part of that buffer (or multiple buffer copies if you want to read more than the internal buffer can hold). This buffer is also stored in virtual memory, unknown where.

And at the lower levels the operating systems have its own buffering too, but it's stored in memory private to the OS. The OS may even have multiple buffers.

As to where all these buffers are stored, one point or another it will be in physical RAM, but it's not under your control, and it doesn't really matter for you as an application programmer. You create your own buffer, ask e.g. `fread` to fill it with data from a file, and that's all you really need to know as a beginner.

Comment: I was going to comment that `fopen` in itself does not read data (which is what the OP assumes); but then I realized *even if* a standard library would do so, then you'd still not have "valid" access to this data until you issue a deliberate `fread`/`fgetc` (etc.). That is, even if a library function *may* "think ahead", it's no use if all you do is `fclose(fopen(..));`.